# Javax Validation is not stable if two or more annotation satisfies the condition on same field

Tags: java, spring-boot, javax.validation

I have observed one issue when I have applied the two validation annotations and both are checking the same conditions in some particular scenario, javax validation output is not stable. Here is the code example:

```
@NotBlank(message = "Date Missing")
@ValidDate(message = "Invalid Date")
private String date;
```

In the above code `ValidDate` is a custom Annotation which is checking if the given date is valid along with not null and `NotBlank` checks null, non empty.

so in case when date is null both are returning true and the message response is toggling between Date Missing and Invalid Date

Is there any way that I can stop this toggling and can use NotBlank only for the null case?

Comment: What if you remove checking of not null in ValidDate custom annotation? Will it satisfy your case

Comment: Even by using @GroupSequence,  you can definite the sequence of execution of validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because order is not guaranteed by default for the execution of javax validations. Therefore, whatever gets executed first throws the error. use [`@GroupSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/GroupSequence.html) for ordering

An alternative would be to check for `Not Blank` as well and throw an appropriate error in your custom annotation `ValidDate` and remove the `@NotBlank` annotation from the property.